# Mac 10.8: Cannot Run MySql

Tags: macos, mysql

I previously had mysql running on my machine. I had to wipe my machine clean yesterday, for an unrelated reason. After I reinstalled mysql today, I received the error

`-bash: mysql: command not found`

When I run `/usr/local/mysql-5.6.10-osx10.7-x86_64/bin/mysql -u root`, this launches mysql. Does this help at all?

I am using Mac OSX 10.8.2. I show that mysql is running in System Preference.

I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How did you install MySQL ? It seems that the mysql executable is not in your PATH.

Try adding it by adding this line: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql-5.6.10-osx10.7-x86_64/bin/`
to your `~/.profile` file

Comment: I installed it with the `.dmg` file. Where can I find the `~/.profile` file? I don't see it in my home directory, where I see files like `.bash_profile`?